# Trying to get wordpress hook post_updated to work

Tags: php, wordpress

I cant get this to work - not sure what Im doing wrong - but Im trying to use post_updated hook instead of the save_post - as I want these values to be inserted after the post has been updated so I can retrieve values from the other custom fields.

```
 function update_meta ($ID = false, $post = false) {
  update_post_meta($ID, 'rest_long', 'Test 1');
  update_post_meta($ID, 'rest_lat', 'Test 2');
}

add_action('post_updated', 'update_meta');
```

Comment: If I use save_post it works - but the problem is that it adds the values when I add new post. What I ultimately want to do is grab the meta data from a different custom field and add to these two fields. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive figure this one out - I was using a custom post type which behaves differently. Ive also switched to save_post and all is working now.